# .NET 4.5 HttpClient request ServicePoint

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I have always used so far:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUri);

do the request
.................
request.ServicePoint.
```

Now I would like to use the new HttpClient from .net 4.5 and I don't know how to access the ServicePoint properties.

Any ideas how can I access the ServicePoint by using HttpClient?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you will have to use the [ServicePointManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.aspx) to do what you want.  Something like;

```
ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(targetUri)
```

Comment: Are you sure HttpWebRequest is used internally in HttpClient? I had a look at [the sources](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/src/System/Net/Http) and could not find any reference to HttpWebRequest.

Comment: @EugeneBeresovsky Not sure at all.  Maybe I read WebClient in my head ( https://www.infoworld.com/article/3198673/application-development/my-two-cents-on-webclient-vs-httpclient-vs-httpwebrequest.html )  I will alter my answer.