# Active connections with HTTPClient C#

Tags: c#, httpclient

I have a problem which I think is related to active connections in the httpclient as documented here

http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/03/24/why-are-webrequests-throttled-i-want-more-throughput/

I need to prove this, how can I get a list of current active connections to a particular url from my application.

Answer (score 2):

The number of "active" connections is not a clearly defined value. You can get the number of currently established connections from the [`ServicePoint.CurrentConnections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.currentconnections.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in the right direction also need this part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174974/net-4-5-httpclient-request-servicepoint